# How to unlock a "disabled" iPhone

Tags: iphone, password

Is there any software esp. forensics and such, that allow me to unlock a disabled iPhone from putting in too many wrong attempts. I know the correct PIN but I don't want to reset it since this contains VERY important data. The screen says iPhone is disabled, and connect to iTunes, but before I do that I just wanted to inquire.

Comment: Not without an Jailbreak I think, or http://www.reuters.com/article/us-apple-encryption-idUSKCN0XQ032

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2016/02/26/iphone-is-disabled-fix/

Answer (score 0):

So since I know the real passcode I will make a iTunes backup of the device, and then I will restore that backup hopefully letting me input another PIN code. :)